# How to implement an unknown class in deep learning neural nets?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am working on multi-class pest classification. I have 10 classes of insects to identify. But the project requirement is to also include an unknown class i.e. if any input comes which doesn't belong to any of the 10 classes, the model should classify it as an 'unknown class.
I am unable to define this unknown class. If anyone have any idea, please help me.
No I have not used any examples of the 'unknown class'. Actually its not feasible as there are unlimited things which can fall beyond the 10 class I have, which could be considered as the 'unknown class'. Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.layers import Dense,GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.applications import MobileNet, ResNet50, InceptionResNetV2
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.mobilenet import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam

base_model=ResNet50(weights='imagenet',include_top=False)

x=base_model.output
x=GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x=Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dense(1024,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dense(512,activation='relu')(x) 
preds=Dense(10,activation='softmax')(x)

model=Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=preds)
class_names = ["acronicta_tridens_caterpillar", "helicoverpa_A",
"helicoverpa_B","helicoverpa_C","helicoverpa_D","helicoverpa_E",
"helicoverpa_F","helicoverpa_H","horned_caterpillar",
"Thistle_Caterpillars"]

for layer in model.layers[:-4]:
    layer.trainable=False
for layer in model.layers[-4:]:
    layer.trainable=True

train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input) 
#included in our dependencies

train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_directory('./project/', # this is 
where you specify the path to the main data folder
                                             target_size=(224,224),
                                             color_mode='rgb',
                                             batch_size=32,
                                             class_mode='categorical',
                                             shuffle=True)

model.compile(optimizer='Adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics= 
['accuracy'])


step_size_train=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
               steps_per_epoch=step_size_train,
               epochs=5)

fn =  "insects.h5"
model.save_weights(fn)

import os
fn =  "insects.h5"
cwd = os.getcwd()
fn2 = cwd+"\\"+fn
print(fn2)
model.load_weights(fn2)

import cv2
gray = cv2.imread("insect1.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
print(gray.shape)
gray = cv2.resize(gray,(224, 224))
print(gray.shape)
pr = model.predict(gray.reshape(1, 224, 224, 3))
pr = model.predict(gray)
print(pr)
for i in range(len(pr)):
    z=[np.argmax(pr[i])]
    print("pr=%s, Predicted=%s" % (pr, z))
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(gray, cmap=plt.get_cmap("Spectral"))
cv2.imshow("", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

class_names = ["acronicta_tridens_caterpillar", "helicoverpa_A", 
"helicoverpa_B","helicoverpa_C","helicoverpa_D","helicoverpa_E",
"helicoverpa_F","helicoverpa_H","horned_caterpillar",
"Thistle_Caterpillars"]
o=class_names[z[0]]
print(o)
```

Comment: Hi, for clarification are there examples of the "unkown" class in your dataset? Second can you show us your model implementation to see how your model is build to help you better?

Comment: No I have not used any examples of the 'unknown class'. Actually its not feasible as there are unlimited things which can fall beyond the 10 class I have, which could be considered as the 'unknown class'. I have edited my post and added my code. Please, have a look at it.

Comment: I am aware that there are possible ulimited things that can fall into "unkown class" but you can train a model with 11 classes 10 for your known and 1 for your unkown . Into the unkown class every object will go which don't belong to the other 10 known classes. I will have a look at your code :)

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch..but yeah its a possibility. I can try it. Thanx :) but please do tell if there's any other way possible.